# Memory management - How to show an already instantiated ViewController without creating a new instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am having major memory management issues. After small use of the program it will crash running out of memory. I have finally found the cause, every time I create a new ViewController rather than accessing the instance, I am creating a new instance.

So app loads and instantiates the FirstViewController. You click a button which instantiates `FilterViewController`. From here when going back to `FirstViewController` I am creating a **new** instance of this as follows:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName
        :@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard 
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

    fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

And repeat process. Any way of presenting the view controller without re-instantiating it? I am close to submitting the app (tomorrow hopefully) so I need to try get this sorted. Thanks!

Here is the presentation of the ViewController.

```
[self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Presenting `FilterViewController` from `FirstViewController`

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender {
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

    self.filterViewController = ctrl;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.filterViewController animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `presentViewController`, you get back to the previous view by calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. You would do that in the method where you're currently creating the new controller.

If you are pushing into a navigation controller you would pop from the navigation controller: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

---

Based on your last update it seems like you don't have a navigation controller and you're just adding the view as a subview and storing the filter view controller. That makes life more complicated really and the correct way to remove it is to setup a delegate relationship so that the filter view controller calls back to the first view controller when it's done and the first controller then transitions the views and nil's the reference.

If you can, change to use a navigation controller properly. You already have half the code, but the first view controller seems to not be in a navigation controller. If you use a nav controller life will be easy...

Comment: Hey thanks for this. So I have put this code in `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"test");
    }];` however it is not going back or adding an NSLog. I have gone to my `FirstViewController` and it has this line: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.filterViewController animated:NO];` so should I try pop it?

Comment: Tried to pop it, however it doesn't do anything, tried `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` which too did nothing

Comment: You added the pop code in a method in the filter view controller? Can you show the code for how you create and show the original controller.

Comment: updated my OP with the edit at the bottom (and yep tried the pop code)

Comment: Oh and `FilterViewController` is a separate .xib if that makes any difference

Comment: It doesn't, once you have the controller instance the issue is how you show it. How you dismiss it has to match how you show it.

Comment: did you see my edit of my post with the code that brings it up?

Comment: Yes, using `transitionFromView`, that's why I edited my answer.